# remove not working properly ? ( of std namespace)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Through this snippet i try to remove a certain file from a directory. Here is the code for that.

```
/* char* cpathToDeleteGND;  
   char* cpathToDeleteFST;
   char* cpathToDeleteSND;
 */

cout << "Enter the name to be removed : ";

cin.ignore();

getline( cin , fullName );

string pathToDeleteGND = "d:/HostelManager/studentDetails/groundFloor/" + fullName  + ".txt";

string pathToDeleteFST = "d:/HostelManager/studentDetails/firstFloor/" + fullName + ".txt";

string pathToDeleteSND = "d:/HostelManager/studentDetails/secondFloor/" + fullName + ".txt";


ifstream checkToDeleteGND( pathToDeleteGND );
ifstream checkToDeleteFST( pathToDeleteFST );
ifstream checkToDeleteSND( pathToDeleteSND );

cpathToDeleteGND = new char[ pathToDeleteGND.size() + 1 ];
cpathToDeleteFST = new char[ pathToDeleteFST.size() + 1 ];
cpathToDeleteSND = new char[ pathToDeleteSND.size() + 1 ];

strcpy( cpathToDeleteGND , pathToDeleteGND.c_str() );
strcpy( cpathToDeleteFST , pathToDeleteFST.c_str() );
strcpy( cpathToDeleteSND , pathToDeleteSND.c_str() );

if( checkToDeleteGND ) {
  if( remove( cpathToDeleteGND) == 0 ) {
   cout << "\nStudent details cleared successfully !";
  }
}  else if( checkToDeleteFST) {
    if( remove( cpathToDeleteFST) == 0 ) {
      cout << "\nStudent details cleared successfully ! ";
            }
   }  else if( checkToDeleteSND ) {
       if( remove( cpathToDeleteSND) == 0 ) {
    cout << "\nStudent details cleared successfully !";
       }
         } else {
        cout << "\nIt seems that either the student has already been removed or does not exist.";
     }
```

I give the name that should be removed from the directory.Though the if else blocks work but the remove function does not work. I can't understand the reason ..

For example , the output goes like :

```
Enter the name to be removed : diana
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The file `diana.txt` existed that's why it didn't execute the last `else` block . But the `remove function` does not work. **Why is that ?**

Comment: From what library are you getting your "remove" function?  It's not a built-in in the language.

Comment: What's with all the string copying? You can just call `remove(pathToDeleteGND.c_str())` since `remove` takes `const char *`. (@MadKeithV: it's standard C.)

Comment: **I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 express** for compiling my code

Comment: @larsmans - after some searching, it seems to be "remove" from <stdio.h>.  There is potential for confusion here, because C++ (per the tags) has a std::remove as well, but that has nothing to do with files.

Comment: @MadKeithV Given that he doesn't say otherwise, I suspect he means the `remove` function from the standard C++ library (in `<cstdio>` or `<stdio.h>`: in the former case, it would be in namespace `std`).

Comment: @James Kanze - I didn't know those existed.  Interesting, though confusing that the std::remove can be even further overloaded with more meanings...  Gotta love C++ ;-)

Comment: @grassPro: the change in title is not informative. The point is that there are several overloads of the name `remove` in the `std` namespace, which are completely unrelated.

Comment: But there's only one `std::remove` which takes only one argument; the others require three arguments.  So there's no real ambiguity.

Answer (score 6):

> The file diana.txt existed that's why it didn't execute the last else block . But the remove function does not work. Why is that?

You don't know because you only print a message if `remove` succeeds. Try:

```
if (remove(pathToDeleteFST.c_str()) == 0) {
    // success, print something
} else {
    // failure, much more interesting
    cout << "Can't remove " << pathToDeleteFST << ": "
         << strerror(errno) << endl;
}
```

`errno` is in `errno.h`, `strerror` in `string.h`.

(Instead of opening the file to check whether it exists, you could also charge ahead and try to `remove` it. As @n.m. notes, that may even be necessary on Windows.)

Answer (score 4):

You open the file before deleting it. Windows won't delete files which are open by someone. Do not check for existence of a file by opening it, use `stat` or just call `remove` without checking.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question but may still be relevant for people who come across this looking for a solution.

The reason this particular example can't delete the file properly is because the files to be deleted are currently being used by the code inside of the `iftream` variables for each.

Before you can `remove` and files, you must first `.close()` them.

If you are having trouble with deleting files that you've previously loaded via `fstream`, ensure that you have properly closed them before trying to use the `remove` function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code, but the probable reason
`remove` fails is that the file is open; Windows will not delete an open 
file.  You should probably refactor a lot of this into separate
functions.  If you used a function like the following, for example:

```
bool
fileExists( std::string const& filename )
{
    return std::ifstream( filename.c_str() );
}
```

, the problem wouldn't occur.  There are other reasons why the open
might fail, but this is a good rough first approximation.  (There are
better ways of testing the existance of a file, but they are system
dependent.)